# How to divide XML tables into arrays with in Python with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I try to divide an xml output from nmap into arrays. The nmap script scans the ssh ciphers of a port and the goal of my python script is to filter the nmap output into insecure ciphers.
The xml output looks like this:

```
<host>
    <ports>
        <port>
            <script>
                <table key="kex_algorithms">
                    <elem>curve25519-sha256</elem>
                    <elem>curve25519-sha256@libssh.org</elem>
                    <elem>ecdh-sha2-nistp256</elem>
                    <elem>ecdh-sha2-nistp384</elem>
                    <elem>ecdh-sha2-nistp521</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group16-sha512</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group18-sha512</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group14-sha256</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group14-sha1</elem>
                </table>
                <table key="server_host_key_algorithms">
                    <elem>rsa-sha2-512</elem>
                    <elem>rsa-sha2-256</elem>
                    <elem>ssh-rsa</elem>
                    <elem>ecdsa-sha2-nistp256</elem>
                    <elem>ssh-ed25519</elem>
                </table>
                <table key="encryption_algorithms">
                    <elem>chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>aes128-ctr</elem>
                    <elem>aes192-ctr</elem>
                    <elem>aes256-ctr</elem>
                    <elem>aes128-gcm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>aes256-gcm@openssh.com</elem>
                </table>
                <table key="mac_algorithms">
                    <elem>umac-64-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>umac-128-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>umac-64@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>umac-128@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-256</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-512</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha1</elem>
                </table>
                    <table key="compression_algorithms">
                    <elem>none</elem>
                    <elem>zlib@openssh.com</elem>
                </table>
            </script>
        </port> 
    </ports>
</host>
```

My current python code:

```
# create element tree object
tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)

# get root element
root = tree.getroot()

# create new arrays
keyx_alg = []
encr_alg = []
mac_alg = []
hkey_alg = []
comp_alg = []


for child in root.findall('host'):
    for gchild in child.findall('ports'):
        for ggchild in gchild.findall('port'):
            for gggchild in ggchild.findall('script'):
                for ggggchild in gggchild.findall('table'):
                    # iterate through the table an append the content into the array
                    # e.g.: iterate trough the table with key="kex_algorithms" and append the content into the array "keyx_alg"
```

I can't figure out how to get the tables into the respective arrays. Maybe one of you knows the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see below (the code collects the tables data into a dict)

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<host>
    <ports>
        <port>
            <script>
                <table key="kex_algorithms">
                    <elem>curve25519-sha256</elem>
                    <elem>curve25519-sha256@libssh.org</elem>
                    <elem>ecdh-sha2-nistp256</elem>
                    <elem>ecdh-sha2-nistp384</elem>
                    <elem>ecdh-sha2-nistp521</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group16-sha512</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group18-sha512</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group14-sha256</elem>
                    <elem>diffie-hellman-group14-sha1</elem>
                </table>
                <table key="server_host_key_algorithms">
                    <elem>rsa-sha2-512</elem>
                    <elem>rsa-sha2-256</elem>
                    <elem>ssh-rsa</elem>
                    <elem>ecdsa-sha2-nistp256</elem>
                    <elem>ssh-ed25519</elem>
                </table>
                <table key="encryption_algorithms">
                    <elem>chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>aes128-ctr</elem>
                    <elem>aes192-ctr</elem>
                    <elem>aes256-ctr</elem>
                    <elem>aes128-gcm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>aes256-gcm@openssh.com</elem>
                </table>
                <table key="mac_algorithms">
                    <elem>umac-64-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>umac-128-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>umac-64@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>umac-128@openssh.com</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-256</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha2-512</elem>
                    <elem>hmac-sha1</elem>
                </table>
                    <table key="compression_algorithms">
                    <elem>none</elem>
                    <elem>zlib@openssh.com</elem>
                </table>
            </script>
        </port> 
    </ports>
</host>'''

data = {}
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for table in root.findall('.//table'):
    data[table.attrib['key']] = [e.text for e in table.findall('elem')]

for k, v in data.items():
    print(f'{k} --> {v}')
```

output

```
kex_algorithms --> ['curve25519-sha256', 'curve25519-sha256@libssh.org', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp256', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp384', 'ecdh-sha2-nistp521', 'diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group16-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group18-sha512', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha256', 'diffie-hellman-group14-sha1']
server_host_key_algorithms --> ['rsa-sha2-512', 'rsa-sha2-256', 'ssh-rsa', 'ecdsa-sha2-nistp256', 'ssh-ed25519']
encryption_algorithms --> ['chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com', 'aes128-ctr', 'aes192-ctr', 'aes256-ctr', 'aes128-gcm@openssh.com', 'aes256-gcm@openssh.com']
mac_algorithms --> ['umac-64-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-128-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com', 'umac-64@openssh.com', 'umac-128@openssh.com', 'hmac-sha2-256', 'hmac-sha2-512', 'hmac-sha1']
compression_algorithms --> ['none', 'zlib@openssh.com']
```